# Query runs longer than command timeout SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package that is using an ADO NET Source component to select a number of rows from a database and inserting these records into another table.

The default command timeout for this component was 30 seconds, however the query can run for much longer than this 30 second period. Running some tests it seems that this timeout period is only to return the very first row. If it manages to do this then the query can run for 1000s of seconds if needed.

If it fails to return a row in the first 30 seconds then the pre-execute part of the component fails. Which I read is the period between starting to execute the query and the first row being returned.

This seems to conflict with anything I can find on google about this property. They seem to say that the command timeout period is to completely execute the query. That is not what I am seeing.

Can anyone clarify what this command timeout period is actually for?

**EDIT:** 
Links to screenshots of the SSIS component and the property (CommandTimeout) that I am querying about.

[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiQ9M.png)

[Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20eZ3.png)

My question isn't about reducing the query time to be within this 30 second timeout period but why executions that take longer than 30 seconds are not timing out.

The 1000 second run of this package was a one of run that moved 17GB~ of data across servers, this isn't a normal run of the package but I was just using it to show that this package is clearly exceeding this 30 second command timeout.

Comment: Can you please update your question with Properties you are having queries with

Comment: 1000 seconds is over 15 minutes. That is entirely too long. My guess is we need to start by fixing the query, then adjusting the timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a client side setting that the client uses to determine if a query is not responding.  The client will then attempt to send a command to the server to cancel the query.

You are correct that the information available is a bit vague, even what is on MSDN.  From my personal observations I agree with your findings that if the client starts to receive data from the server before the timeout then it can run for as long as it takes.

I think of it this way.  When the first row of data is ready to be returned then the query itself is finished and only the movement of data is left to do.  So, by definition the query did not time out.

Comment: Thanks, that was my assumption based on the testing I did, I just couldn't find any resources to back it up online

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/SQLMonger/archive/2011/02/13/first-forayndashabout-timeout.aspx
This also seems to say the same thing